# Strange behavior of temporary auto increment column in MySQL against HAVING clause

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, temp-tables, having

Assume we have a table named **Test** with a single column **col1** (Varchar(10)).
For the sake of this example, assume it has the following data:

```
col1
a
b
c
d
```

Now, I want to select the data in **col1** and add a temporary auto-increment column, which we will call **Rank**. The following query does the job:

```
SELECT
(@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS Rank, Test.col1
FROM Test 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt := 0) AS tmp;
```

The result is

```
Rank col1
1    a
2    b
3    c
4    d
```

No problems so far. Now assume we need to select the rows with Rank larger than 1. I do the following:

```
SELECT
(@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS Rank,  Test.col1
FROM Test 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt := 0) AS tmp
having Rank > 1;
```

The result becomes

```
Rank col1
3    b
5    c
7    d
```

Notice that the first item in the Rank column is 3 rather than 2 as one would expect naturally. Can someone please point out a possible reason for this?

> Why does the Rank (the temporary auto-increment) jump form 2 to 3 ?

The MySQL version is 5.6.32-78.1.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of unexpected things that can happen when you use variables. Some of those are listed in [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html):

> In a SELECT statement, each select expression is evaluated only when sent to the client. This means that in a HAVING, GROUP BY, or ORDER BY clause, referring to a variable that is assigned a value in the select expression list does not work as expected

The exact details vary, but in your case, your increment is evaluated twice (once in the `select`, once for `having`), so it basically behaves like

```
SELECT (@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS Rank,  Test.col1
FROM Test 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt := 0) AS tmp
having (@cnt := @cnt + 1) > 1;
```

One way around this is to force MySQL to evaluate the expression beforehand.

The proper solution (as far as possible when using variables) is probably:

```
select (
   SELECT (@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS Rank,  Test.col1
   FROM Test 
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt := 0) AS tmp
) x
where Rank > 1;
```

`where Rank > 1` (without the subquery) is likely what you originally intended to do anyway.

But you can also do this by other means. In your example, you should be able to use

```
SELECT (@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS Rank,  Test.col1
FROM Test 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt := 0) AS tmp
group by col1    
having Rank > 1;
```

Unless `col1` is a primary key candidate (e.g. unique not null), MySQL needs to actually  evaluate the expression to do the `group by`. On the other hand, if `col1` *is* e.g. the primary key, MySQL can optimize the `group by` away and you are back at your original situation - if it *does* do it may depend on your MySQL version, but afaik MySQL 5.6 should do this.

Side note: since `rank` became a keyword in MySQL 8, you should not use it as an alias in case you ever intend to upgrade.

Comment: thanks for your helpful comments (+1) ! I did eventually used the wrapping of the query without HAVING into another SELECT, which you pointed out above. I was still curious though what's going on behind the scenes. As far as I understand now, and your answer seems to also suggest it, the temporary added column wasn't materialized yet at the time of applying the HAVING clause, and that should be the reason of the unexpected result. Interestingly still, the restriction implied by the HAVING produced correct results for the col1, it was the Rank itself that got mixed up.